# formating return string for map as a string but get errors

Tags: java

i have this

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Relatives
{
    private Map<String,Set<String>> map;


    public Relatives()
    {
        map = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();
    }

    public void setPersonRelative(String line)
    {
        String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
        String person = personRelative[0];
        String relative = personRelative[1];

        if(map.containsKey(person))
        {
            map.get(person).add(relative);
        }
        else
        {
            Set<String> relatives = new TreeSet<String>();
            relatives.add(relative);
            map.put(person,relatives);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the String version of the set containing person's relatives
     * (see last line of sample output)
     * @param person the person whose relative set should be returned as a String
     * @param the string version of person's relative set
     */
    public String getRelatives(String person)
    {
        return map.keySet();
    }
```

how can i return a  map as a string and make it look like this

> Bob is related to John Tom
>   Dot is related to Chuck Fred Jason Tom
>   Elton is related to Linh

i have tried typecasting although i didnt think it would work and parse which also didnt work and taht is what i have currently

Comment: iterate the map contents and print them as you wish (Hint: `Map.iterator()`)

Comment: for the current one the error is incompatable types

Comment: correction: get the `set` from the `map` (you already know how to do this)` and iterate over the set to build the String that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like this:

```
public String getRelatives(String person)
{        
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(person);
    sb.append(" is related to ");
    for(String relative : map.get(person))
    {
        sb.append(relative);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or if you want to get a little more complicated, and handle the case where someone isn't related to anyone nicely:

```
public String getRelatives(String person)
{   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(person);
    Set<String> relatives = map.get(person);
    if(relatives == null || relatives.isEmpty())
    {
        sb.append("is not related to anyone.");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append(" is related to ");
        for(String relative : relatives)
        {
            sb.append(relative);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Provided you initialized the map correctly, and the sets that the map maps to, you should be fine.

Basically you create a `StringBuilder` (which may be overkill for this, but it's still good practice), stuff it with the things you want, then call its `.toString()` method.

The for loop just iterates over the contents of the `Set`, and stuffs the relative's name in the StringBuilder, along with a space character to space things out.

---

Other notes:

```
private Map<String,Set<String>> map;


public Relatives()
{
    map = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();
}
```

Can just be:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

or, if using Java 7, simply:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

(Note that this way, there's no need for an explicit constructor if it was just for initializing the map)

I'd also change this:

```
if(map.containsKey(person))
{
    map.get(person).add(relative);
}
else
{
    Set<String> relatives = new TreeSet<String>();
    relatives.add(relative);
    map.put(person,relatives);
}
```

To:

```
if(!map.containsKey(person))
{
    map.put(person, new TreeSet<String>());
}
map.get(person).add(relative);
```

Simpler, and avoids redundancy