# toString error cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

i am working n this lab for school and have am doing something wrong with my toString
this is what i have

```
public String getRelatives(String person)
{
    String s = "";
    s+=(person);
    s+=(" is related to ");

    for(String relative : map.get(person))
    {
        s+=(relative);
        s+=(' ');
    }
        return s;
}


    /**
     * returns the String version of the entire map listing each key person and all of
     * their relatives
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";

        return getRelatives();
    }
```

i want it too look like this

```
Bob is related to John Tom
Dot is related to Chuck Fred Jason Tom
Elton is related to Linh
```

i know i am doing something wrong in my toString but to me at least it makes sence and am not sure how i should do it

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: If you fix your indentation (at least in your post, if not your code), it will help both of us.

Comment: how do you mean? what did i miss indent?

Comment: I realize you're eager to get this lab done, but please limit the number of posts you make about the same issue, and/or spend sometime yourself debugging before coming back here and posting your latest iteration.  [Your previous question addressing a very similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040622/formating-return-string-for-map-as-a-string-but-get-errors/19040659#19040659) hasn't even been up for 30 minutes.

Comment: and in 30 minutes i messed with it and arrived at another problem although i get your point and apologize

Comment: @user2809082, but what's the point?  You obviously paid very little attention to the help that was given on the previous question (your code in *this* question as evidence of that), so why keep asking questions if you ignore the answers?

Answer (score 1):

The declared method getRelatives() takes a String as an argument. When you are calling it in the toString() method, you are not passing a String argument to it. Therefore, it gives you an error.

Comment: how would i change it to pass a string

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. I can't read your mind :)